# difficulty in understanding closures

Tags: javascript, closures

Why this code returns `43` as the result, I expect it to result `42`. The code is as follows:

```
function say667() {
  // Local variable that ends up within closure
  var num = 42;
  var say = function() { console.log(num); }
  num++;
  return say;
}
var sayNumber = say667();
sayNumber();
```

Comment: Why? Because you call the inner function ***after*** `num` has been incremented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've closed over the **variable** `num`, not the value the variable has at the time you define the function.

This is the order of events:

1. You assign 42 to `num`
2. You increment `num` to 43
3. You return a function and store it in `sayNumber`
4. You call that function, which reads the value of `num`, which is `43`